# Unable to install windows 95 ( Need to access .qic backup disks)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, backup, windows-backup

I wish to read some old .qic backup disks which were made in Win95 or Win98.  My reserve PC runs Windows XP and I have tried to install Win95 or Win98 on to its second hard drive.  When I insert the installation disk it starts to run but the "Install software option"  is "greyed out" and if I click on any of the others I get the message "re-insert CD".  Is there a way round the installation problem or an alternative way of accessing the backups?

Comment: running it in a VM sounds like a decent idea

Comment: Keep in mind, that as unlikely as it sounds, its possible your pc is simply too new. (architecture and instructions not supported, and in extreme cases, the cpu can be too fast) Running inside a VM may be the only thing you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this `msbkwin.lzh`](http://www.willsworks.net/downloads/msbkwin.lzh?attredirects=0) tool. It made exactly for your case - extract files from old MSQIC and NTBKUP archives. You can unpack `msbkwin.lzh` archive with [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)

You can check other related utilities from the same author by navigating to
   http://www.willsworks.net/downloads/

P.S.

`msbkwin.lzh` is MSqic and NTbkup extraction tools.
It is open source program, so if one want to explore it, here is [link](http://www.willsworks.net/downloads/msbksrc.lzh?attredirects=0) to source code of this program

Inside of archive of [`msbkwin.lzh`](http://www.willsworks.net/downloads/msbkwin.lzh?attredirects=0) one can find full documentation how to use it as well description of QIC and NTBackup file format.

Below is excerpt from help file on usage:

```
msqic <file> [@] -p [-x] [-t] [-v]  [-s{c|d}#] [-f{d|e|s}] [-d] [-r]
 @<cmd> to extract directories based on command file
-p<path> extract all FILES from ONE path in directory tree
-x to extract file, nm, using paths in tree structure
-t[ds] to display catalog as tree, d => directory only, s => with segment info
-v just display VTBL and exit
-fd find file id 0x33cc33cc in data
-fe find file id 0x66996699 in data
-fs find & display compressed file segments
-sc# force start catalog (directory set) at hex offset
-sd# force start data region at hex offset
-st95  force Win95 decompression decode, default is Win98 & ME
-D to decompress archive and write output to dcomp.out
-d##[:#] to decompress a segment(s) starting at hex offset ## in file
     use optional hex :cnt to decompress cnt contiguous segments
-r[filter] attempt raw file data recovery, use -sd to set data region start 
     use optional filter string, ie *.txt, to limit hits
```

Comment: This seems like a much better solution than mine for this particular problem

Comment: So I upvoted it

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments of other, but I will also answer it here:

Running it in a Virtual Machine (VM) may be the only course of action here.

You can get VirtualBox for free from ([Here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads))

You shouldn't need a large virtual hard disk, I would say about 1-2 GB should be enough.
Ram can be 64mb or 128mb, nothing extreme.

If the files are on a floppy drive and you have one on your computer you can connect that up in the virtual machine options prior to boot.

Read the documentation if are not sure how to use Virtual Box,
Or Video on Windows 95 in Virtual Box ([Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlBB9OKff2A))

I hope this helps...

Comment: If its just to grab data, its good enough. Virtualbox MIGHT have some issues with windows 95.  Windows 98 is stuck at 640x480

Comment: Virtualbox **does** have issues with Windows 95.  If you don't plan to play with virtualization (other than this one time), I recommend using Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 instead.  I have installed Windows 98 on that before and it runs great.

Comment: Another option:  provided you can get your hands on an installation CD for Windows NT 4.0 (and Service Pack 6a) - and provided your software would run on that - that would run well in Virtualbox.

Comment: I just posted on software I am familiar with. But yes, if Microsoft Virtual PC works better with windows 98 and/or 95, by all mean, people should use that. I use Linux (Debian Mate) so running Windows Programs natively is usually not an option unless it is supported in Wine.